# Can I open Oracle MAF custom springboard with swipe event?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-maf

I am using custom springboard with .amx page in my MAF application. But as we see in other apps, they open springboard on swipe event, can we do same thing in MAF/ADF app?

Comment: Swiping where? Anywhere on the screen?

Comment: Not anywhere, swipe should occur only from the left edge.

Comment: According to this document: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/ADFMobileDesign/Pattern+-+Springboard it should be possible somehow

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can swipe to show the springboard. Add 'Action Listener' to the page and set the following attribute to it. Give type as 'swipeRight' and binding as '#{bindings.gotoSpringboard.execute}'. Make sure the binding to gotoSpringboard is created. However , actionListener could only be added to Command Actions. So , I guess we should enclose the page content inside a Command Link.

Comment: So while setting swipeRight to action , whether the click even will work?